# boost::asio::thread_pool - How to cancel workers before work is finished?

Tags: boost, threadpool

OS windows. I would like to create a back-buffer before paint. I want to use boost::asio::thread_pool to increase speed. I need to stop back-buffer creating, if my "input data"(tasks) is updated.
I wrote Test_CreateAndCancel function to simplify test.

```
class Task
{
public:
    virtual void operator()
    {
        std::cout << "Task started " << std::endl;
        DoSomeWork();
        std::cout << "Task in progress" << std::endl;

        for (int i = 0; i < 15; ++i)
             boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(1000));

        std::cout << "Task ended" << std::endl;
    }
};
using TaskPtr = std::shared_ptr<Task>;


void Test_CreateAndCancel(std::vector<TaskPtr> &tasks)
{
    //start back-buffer creating
    boost::asio::thread_pool _thread_pool(4);
    for (auto task : tasks)
    {
         boost::asio::post(thread_pool, [task] {
             task->operator()();
        });
    }

    //  simulate cancel 
    thread_pool.stop(); // wait untill all threads are finished?
}
```

vector tasks has 4 items.
Result is: 4 "Task started" "Task in progress" "Task ended"

I am thinking to add custom IsCanceled() checkes in task::operator().

Is there are any other ways to make my tasks cancelable?
How can I implement cancel logic?

I will be grateful for any advices
Thanks

Comment: Compare https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.tutorial.interruption, or  chapter 9 from [Concurrency In Action](https://www.manning.com/books/c-plus-plus-concurrency-in-action#toc) (free online from Manning)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach is to add a (probably atomic) variable "please_stop" to your Task and

- query it inside the operator() regularly
- set it from the outside (another task)

---

The basic problem is that you cannot cancel an operation that is running in a different task. You can only "ask it politely" to stop working.

---

boost::thread has an interrupt mechanism (see the link, @sehe posted above). This basically does not do anything different than what I suggested, except it's baked into boost::thread. There are certain "interruption points" that will query the "please stop" state and throw an exception, if it is set.

You have to catch the exception though, otherwise the thread itself will stop and you want only the operation to stop.

So you could do something like this:

```
class Task {
   virtual void operator()()
   {
      try {
         do_something();
         boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::chrono::seconds(10000);
      }
      catch (boost::thread_interrupted&) { // 
         handle_please_stop_request();
      }
   }
};

// and later
   task_thread.interrupt();
```

---

The problem with this approach is that you have to know the thread and you probably want to interrupt not the thread but the operation. Which is why the atomic approach has its charms.

BTW, your example has several problems. The task operation (operator()()) never stops at all. You are creating a task pool for every vector of tasks. I assume these are just artifacts of your example and your real world code is different.

One thing though. I haven't looked into asio::thread_pool yet, but I am missing the boost::asio::work object. Search stackoverflow on how to use the work object.